# Netlogo about empty spaces between turtles and patches

Tags: netlogo

Hey Here I'm trying to setup patches (say white) on the last row ("min-pycor") with precentage 9-1 to blank (which means we have randomly 90% white patches on the last row and blank 10%). I did that. But the thing I don't know how to do is: how to create turtles randomly on the same row (min-pycor) on the blank. So everytime we setup the view we get on the row "min-pycor" random 90% white pathes and random 10% of turtle only on the blank. Thanks I got the answer but still there are some empty spaces between turtles and patches I couldn't get rid of

```
to setup
clear-all
ask patches [
if pycor = min-pycor [
  ifelse random 10 <= 2 
    [set pcolor white]
    [sprout 1 [set shape "square" set color blue] ] 
]    ]

reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: sorry, can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Your random code represents an 30% chance of a patch being white, not 90%. Random 10 produces values from 0 to 9. "<= 2" means that the values 0, 1, and 2 will make the statement true. So, 0, 1, 2 will produce a white patch, while 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 will produce a blue turtle on a black patch.

Comment: The "square" turtle shape is slightly smaller than the patch. That is, the square shape at size 1 will leave the edge of the patch visible. Is this the "empty space" to which you refer?